# How do I create a query on a type which includes a relation in graphql/prisma?

Tags: mongodb, graphql, prisma-graphql

I have a type "Contract" which includes a "User" which is a relation. I am looking to write a mutation to include the User.

I thought that User just stored the ID so my mutation looked like this:

```
mutation createContract {
  createContract(
    data: {
      contract_no: "999"
      user: "5cb0994e24aa9a0008fde672"
      contractItems: {
        create: [
          {
            title: "new contract item"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ) {
    id
    contract_no
    contractItems {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

The error includes the phrase "Reason: 'user' Expected 'UserCreateOneInput', found not an object. ", IU think that it should be a fairly simple syntax thing. By the way; contractItems have an @embedded directive on them.

Comment: Look for docs on using field Resolvers in graphql.

Comment: Refer this link :  https://medium.com/paypal-engineering/graphql-resolvers-best-practices-cd36fdbcef55

 Look for the section, `Fetching data at a field-level`

Comment: Can you share code for resolver? or are you directly calling prisma API? If yes, then you need to have nested mutation for `user` field connecting contract to user.

Answer (score 0):

I had not set a connection even though the datamodel has an @relation directive against user. Line 5 should read

user: { connect: {id : "5cbae19924aa9a0008fde67c"} }

Thanks to everyone for commenting.